# Android Google Analytics EasyTracker

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I'm trying to use Google Analytics in my Android application with 
[Google Configuration](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/android.html)

1. Add .jar in my project
2. Insert this in AndroidManifest

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   ```
3. Add this in my java file

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   ```
   GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

               tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
               tracker.startNewSession("My-UA–XXXXXXXX", this);


               setContentView(R.layout.main);
               Button createEventButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.NewEventButton);
               createEventButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                   tracker.trackEvent(
                       "Clicks",  // Category
                       "Button",  // Action
                       "clicked", // Label
                       77);       // Value
                 }
               });

               setContentView(R.layout.main);

               Button createPageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.NewPageButton);
               createPageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                   // Add a Custom Variable to this pageview, with name of "Medium" and value "MobileApp" and
                   // scope of session-level.
                   tracker.setCustomVar(1, "Navigation Type", "Button click", 2);
                   // Track a page view. This is probably the best way to track which parts of your application
                   // are being used.
                   // E.g.
                   // tracker.trackPageView("/help"); to track someone looking at the help screen.
                   // tracker.trackPageView("/level2"); to track someone reaching level 2 in a game.
                   // tracker.trackPageView("/uploadScreen"); to track someone using an upload screen.
                   tracker.trackPageView("/testApplicationHomeScreen");
                 }
               });

               Button quitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.QuitButton);
               quitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                   finish();
                 }
               });

               Button dispatchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.DispatchButton);
               dispatchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                   // Manually start a dispatch, not needed if the tracker was started with a dispatch
                   // interval.
                   tracker.dispatch();
                 }
               });




   }

   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy();
     // Stop the tracker when it is no longer needed.
     tracker.stopSession();
   }
   }
   ```

==> And it's ok, no error, compiling and executing but i have created my ua account yesterday (more 24h) and i have nothing in my google analytics panel.

My Question : is there an error in my code or i want to wait again ? Live trafic works for Android application (like tradicional website) ???
I have no information about Live trafic (when i play my app, i would like to show the number of person using my application) and Saved trafic (with viewed pages, time)

Thank you for your replies and excuse my poor english :)

bye

---

**UPDATE 1 :** 
i've used this tuto : http://www.xatik.com/2012/03/27/how-to-use-google-analytics-in-android-applications/ and i've got this in my Logcat :

```
04-07 14:21:59.669: INFO/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(864): Host: www.google-analytics.com
04-07 14:21:59.669: INFO/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(864): User-Agent: GoogleAnalytics/1.4.2 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; sdk Build/FRF91)
04-07 14:21:59.669: INFO/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(864): GET /__utm.gif?utmwv=4.8.1ma&utmn=235327630&utme=8(1!Navigation%20Type)9(1!Button%20click)11(1!2)&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=240x320&utmul=en-US&utmp=%2FtestApplicationHomeScreen&utmac=BLIBLUBLIBLO–1&utmcc=more_and_more
```

in progress but nothing in my Live Analytics panel....
i've added EasyTracker .jar in my project
Here my Activity Code:

```
import com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker;
import com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.EasyTracker;
import com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.TrackedActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends TrackedActivity {

    GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);

                Button quitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.QuitButton);
                quitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                        EasyTracker.getTracker().trackEvent("ButtonClick", "MyButtonName", "", 0);
                  }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      //How can i stop the tracking onDestroy ???
    }

}
```

Comment: Turn on debugging and what do you get in your LogCat, anything? You turn on debuggin by adding this to your strings.xml `<bool name="ga_debug">true</bool>`

Comment: i'm trying this, i add this line to my strings.xml but why ? i've nothing in my logCat, just my Log.i for test before and after my tracker.trackEvent...

Comment: Turning this variable to true allows the Google Analytics library to print out its own Log statements. Oh maybe my comment is just directed at EasyTracker. It much easier: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/android.html#eztracker

Comment: ok thank, i'm trying EasyTracker method :)

Comment: do you have the INTERNET permission in your Manifest?

Comment: i used EasyTracker now and i've updated my first message...

Comment: @Blundell: The official Google documentation about mobile analytics/EasyTracker is unreliable, inconsistent, and outdated.

Comment: Yep as with most Android documentation! http://blog.blundell-apps.com/google-analytics-common-problems-and-fixes/

Answer (score 8):

I know this is a couple months old but I'll give a response to potentially help others. I am the person who wrote the guide that was referenced in Update 1 of the OP. One issue I originally ran into was the fact that I was using a custom ROM on my phone. A lot of custom ROMs have modified 'hosts' files that block an apps access to display ads or in this case blocks the sending of data to Google Analytics. If you do have a custom ROM on your phone, you can check the 'hosts' file to see if Google Analytics is listed in there. The fastest way to do this is to open the file in a text editor on your computer. To do this:

1. Get a file explorer app on you android device (I use 'ES File Explorer').
2. Navigate to '/etc'.
3. Locate and copy the 'hosts' file to a known location on your SD card.
4. Connect phone/SD card to computer and open the 'hosts' file in a text editor (Notepad++ is nice and free).
5. Search through file for anything that relates to Google Analytics and delete it. I first searched for 'analytics', went through all results, and deleted everything that had something to do with Google attached to the name (there are other analytic sites). Then I searched for 'google', went through all the results, and deleted anything that still related to Analytics.
6. Save 'hosts' file.
7. Disconnect from computer and use file explorer to copy the 'hosts' file from SD card back to '/etc' and overwrite.

This should allow your phone to send data to Google Analytics. I will update my guide to include this somewhere.

Comment: It works only if you have some AdBlock app. You can simply disable it or uninstall. So if you haven't such app your hosts will have only one line: "127.0.0.1 localhost"